# How to let the default python use the `/usr/local/python`?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have two python on Ubuntu:

```
which python 
/home/summer/anaconda2/bin/python
```

I want to the default python use the `/usr/bin/python`, 
how to realize it?

Comment: Firstly, don't post pictures of text; just paste the text into your question.  Speaking of adding things to your question, please also edit in the result of `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: Do not do that. Python is used also for some system utilities. You will overwrite python and you never know what some utilities will fail. -- So, just install python locally for your user (and possibly with pip / pyenv) so that you can have parallel version of python, according the specific uses.

Comment: It doesn't sound like OP is trying to _replace_ the stock Python, but rather to actually _use_ it by default rather than the one installed in `~summer`.  That said, please clarify whether `pythoon` is a typo or not.